# Sqlite Insert or Replace don't update one column

Tags: ios, iphone, sqlite

I am using Insert or Update for data. I have a table sub_sub_categories, there is a column is_favorite default value is 0, I set it 1 when when user Add To Favorite. On every app launch I Insert or Replace all data from web. When I do this it also sets the is_favorite to 0. Althought I am not setting it. How to stop it updating is_favorite column. Here is my code.

```
for (int i=0; i < arraySubSubCategories.count; i++) {
    id dict = [arraySubSubCategories objectAtIndex:i];

    NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT OR REPLACE into sub_sub_categories (id, name, sub_category_id, problem_name, problem_description, why, why_link, solution, solution_link, sort_order, is_deleted) VALUES (%@, '%@', %@, '%@', '%@', '%@', '%@', '%@', '%@', %@, %@)",
                       [dict objectForKey:@"id"],
                       [MyCommonFunctions addSlashes:[dict objectForKey:@"name"]],
                       [dict objectForKey:@"sub_category_id"],
                       [MyCommonFunctions addSlashes:[dict objectForKey:@"problem_name"]],
                       [MyCommonFunctions addSlashes:[dict objectForKey:@"problem_description"]],
                       [MyCommonFunctions addSlashes:[dict objectForKey:@"why"]],
                       [MyCommonFunctions addSlashes:[dict objectForKey:@"why_link"]],
                       [MyCommonFunctions addSlashes:[dict objectForKey:@"solution"]],
                       [MyCommonFunctions addSlashes:[dict objectForKey:@"solution_link"]],
                       [dict objectForKey:@"sort_order"],
                       [dict objectForKey:@"is_deleted"]];

    [MyCommonFunctions InsUpdateDelData:query];
}
```

**Edit** Query is:

```
INSERT OR REPLACE into sub_sub_categories (id, name, sub_category_id, problem_name, problem_description, why, why_link, solution, solution_link, sort_order, is_deleted) VALUES (93, 'some data', 6, '', 'some data', 'some data', '', 'some data', 'some data', 0, 0)
```

Comment: your try insert new data not for updating check your query

Answer (score 2):

`INSERT OR REPLACE` does not keep previous value inside db, it overwrites it with value given or default values.

You have to query your database first to get existing fields (if record exist) and put the one you don't want to replace in your query.